# Qt: c++: how to read a ".dat" file

Tags: c++, readline, qfile

I have a ".dat" file that contains "1"s and "-1"s as a sequence in a vertical representation (i.e.: each element is in a single line.).

I am trying to read the file as follow:

```
char buf[30];
QFile sequence("Sequences.dat");
sequence.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
for(int sym=0; sym<29; sym++){
    char c = symbols[sym] = sequence.readLine(buf,sizeof(buf));
    symbols[sym] = c;
}
sequence.close();
```

however, the result is nothing like my sequence as seen below:

[image]

what did I did wrong ?

Comment: Post an excerpt from Sequences.dat

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: SEQLEN is 30 and I am subtracting 1 from it to become 29. so, in total I will have 30 iteration from 0 to 29.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: could not understand your comment

Answer (score 2):

Check the [`readLine`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#readLine) API doc: the return value is the number of bytes read, while the line is read into the `buf` array, which is overwritten at each iteration. Note that the first symbol of the inspected array is a `'\0'` (empty string), probably because the last line of your file is empty.

Comment: Not according to the [Qt docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#readLine)

Comment: "A terminating '\0' byte is always appended to data", which is what's happened. Your buffer stores the results of the last attempt to read from file. When sequence reaches its eof, it reads nothing and appends \0 to it. Since you always read to buf, your cycle is constantly overwriting the previously read.